# Passing more then 100 arguments to ColdFusion function throws an error

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

There is a ColdFusion function where we have to pass more then 100 arguments to get a search result. When passing these 100 odd parameters into the function, ColdFusion throws the error: "`404 not found`"

I tried to increase post size Limit in CF server settings from 100 to 300 but am still getting the error.

Comment: This won't answer your question, but are you sure you need to pass 100 parameters? Can't you cluster them into structured data types?

Comment: The OP is _probably_ stuck on the form field limit (which defaults to 100, and also gets reset to 100 when upgrading to 9.0.2), not arguments, so they're not getting to the point of being able to collate the data into structs (though that's probably a sensible approach for simplifying if there is an actual function with too many args).

Comment: Could you use form method="GET" ("url" scope) instead of POST ("form" scope)? There is not limit on url parameters.

Answer (score 13):

Increasing the "post size limit" only changes how many *megabytes* can be received, not the quantity.

For that, you need to increase the "post **parameters** limit" in `neo-runtime.xml`, by adding* or updating the XML node:

```
<var name='postParametersLimit'><number>300.0</number></var>
```

Then save the file and **restart the ColdFusion server** for the changes to take effect.

<sub>* If the 'postParametersLimit' field is not present, you can insert it immediately *before* `<var name='postSizeLimit'>` - whilst it's not mandatory to place it there specifically, this is a simple way to ensure it does not get nested invalidly.</sub>

Note that this affects the number of **form fields** (i.e. HTTP POST parameters) being submitted - not the number of arguments to a function, but this is presumably your problem because the latter should not cause a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks, checking it now Peter.

Comment: Note: if this isn't in your neo-runtime.xml (it won't be by default), add it just before `<var name='postSizeLimit'>` (which should be there by default)

Answer (score 10):

In ColdFusion 10, the post parameters limit is a setting in the Administrator:

Server Settings / Settings / Request Size Limits / Maximum number of POST request parameters

This setting defaults to 100.

Increase it to the required amount of parameters required to be accepted.
(We just had to increase ours to 300!)

Comment: Yep. However, the OP is using CF9 which does not expose that setting in the CF Administrator screen (it was added in CF10). Instead they will need to [modify the neo-runtime.xml settings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19348441/104223) as Peter suggested. See [ColdFusion 9.0 Update 2 - Changes to CF Administrator](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/release-note/coldfusion-9-0-update-2.html)

Comment: Yup - Sorry missed the "9" tag!

Comment: Still valid information though - it's possible people on CF10 will find this page too.

Comment: @Gavin - Yep, I figured. Just an FYI for the CF9 folks, so they do not waste time looking for the setting in the CF9 Admin screen :)

Comment: @GavinBaumanis Your response helped as I found this setting in ColdFusion2016 as well.