# CF 10 crashes on a large number of form fields

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

When submitting a large number of form fields, ColdFusion 10 crashes even if ColdFusion 9 does not.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing more then 100 arguments to ColdFusion function throws an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348207/passing-more-then-100-arguments-to-coldfusion-function-throws-an-error). FYI: As mentioned in the other thread, the limit was added in CF9.0.2.

Comment: The error message and solution is different for CF 10

Comment: Different how? The CF10 solution on the other thread is change the `Maximum number of POST request parameters` setting, just as you posted below.

Comment: It is different because you don't manually edit an xml file to make this go away + Error message is different on CF 9

Comment: The other question was tagged for CF 9. I do see that a CF 10 solution is also included.

Comment: Yes, that is the one. It is the same basic issue, and the solution is the same. There are a few others similar threads too. I am surprised it did not turn up in your searches. The question comes up a lot lately, as people upgrade.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Earlier versions of ColdFusion 9 did not restrict the number of form fields that could be submitted. ColdFusion 10, be default limits the number of fields to 100.

If you go to Server Settings -> Settings then the to Request Size Limits section. There is a setting  called `Maximum number of POST request parameters`. It needs to be adjusted upward

Answer (score 2):

As Leigh mentioned (I can personally attest to this), this limit was actually added in 9.0.2. The problem was that there was no way to change it in the admin UI, had to do it in XML.

Comment: Yep, for CF9 you have to modify the setting in [neo-runtime.xml](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19348441/104223).

Comment: Actually the _ability to_ limit was added with [ColdFusion Security Hotfix APSB12-06](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-security-hotfix.html) which could be applied to versions ColdFusion 9.0.1, ColdFusion 9.0, ColdFusion 8.0.1 and ColdFusion 8 as well. Although you would have to manually edit the `neo-runtime.xml` file to enable the limit. ColdFusion 9.0.2 was the first version to enable it by default. Just wanted to add this for future reference.

Comment: *ColdFusion 9.0.2 was the first version to enable it by default* Duh, you are right @Miguel-F. I forgot about that. Good clarification.

Comment: @Leigh I'm still not sure that it was enabled by default in 9.0.2 either. Looking at the [release notes](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/release-note/coldfusion-9-0-update-2.html) they still mention manually editing the file. ??? Good ol' Adobe documentation. Anyway, I was just trying to point out that this could be an issue in previous versions if the hotfix has been applied.

Comment: @Miguel-F - I think it is, but I would have to check to be certain. (As an aside, those release notes are dreadful ... *very* confusing.)

Answer (score 0):

In ColdFusion – 9:
First install the security fix( http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-security-hotfix.html ) for ColdFusion - 9.

- Go to {ColdFusion-Home}/lib for Server Installation
- **OR:** {ColdFusion-Home}/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib for **Multiserver or J2EE installation**.
- Open file **neo-runtime.xml**
- After the line: `<var name='postSizeLimit'><number>100.0</number></var>`
- Add the line `<var name='postParametersLimit'><number>100.0</number></var>`

You can change the limit as per your need.

Comment: *Add the line ...* But do a search first just to make sure that key does not already exist. If it is mistakenly entered twice, one of the values will be ignored (most likely the new entry).