# enable more form fields per post coldfusion

Tags: forms, post, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We have developed an app that allows users to add multiple items to the cart in one movement.

We are using coldfusion 10 and have noticed there is a limitation on how many form fields you can post per request.

Does anyone know if there is an easy way to override this via application.cfc at all ?

Comment: You can't override it via Application.cfc - you need to edit the neo-runtime.xml config file, or use CF Administrator to modify it for you - see [Passing more then 100 arguments to ColdFusion function throws an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348207/passing-more-then-100-arguments-to-coldfusion-function-throws-an-error)

Comment: CF 10 is also covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664441/cf-10-crashes-on-a-large-number-of-form-fields